# Calling Powershell from C# and handling exception

Tags: c#, powershell

I am calling Powershell scripts from C# using Process.Start(). How do I capture exceptions that are raised by the Powershell script in the C# code?

Comment: you cant, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320767/how-to-catch-exceptions-from-processes-in-c-sharp/320779#320779

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hosting the PowerShell engine in C# is pretty simple.  This code uses a bit dated API but it still works and gives you an idea of what is involved:

```
string cmd = @"Get-ChildItem $home\Documents -recurse | " +
              "Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7))} | " +
              "Sort Fullname | Foreach {$_.Fullname}";

Runspace runspace = null;
Pipeline pipeline = null;

try
{
    runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmd);
    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        // Consume the results
        Debug.WriteLine(obj);    
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
}
finally
{
    if (pipeline != null) pipeline.Dispose();
    if (runspace != null) runspace.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I am getting the following exception while trying to run a one-liner script with just a write-host in it:
**Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it.**

Comment: Yeah you won't be able to use Write-Host unless you implement a PowerShell host. It is a reasonable chunk of code.  You can either avoid *-Host cmdlets and use Write-Output instead.  Or for a sample host impl, look here: http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/make-ps1exewrapper/  Click on the SkyDrive link to download (don't try to copy from the blog post).

Comment: Just a note, you don't need to pass `cmd` to `runspace.CreatePipeline`.

Comment: Oops, that was a tad redundant. :-) Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies, I can't work out how to comment on Keith's answer.

Do you not need to check `if (pipeline.error.Count > 0)` and then make use of `pipeline.error.Read()` ?

I've been led to believe the try/catch you have won't handle any errors that occur at the runspace level.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to interact with powershell you should not use process.start but instead [host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) powershell.

Comment: This doesn't mean creating a complete PowerShell Host: you just need a [`Runspace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace(VS.85).aspx) instance.