# How can I catch all exceptions in C# from libtiff.net TIFFCP.exe

Tags: c#

How can I catch all exceptions in C# from libtiff.net TIFFCP.exe
I would like to get exceptions from TTIFFCP.exe(Merge, Split) such as DirectoryNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException ... 
I can see these errors on visula studio debugger window but it does not pass catch block.

I tried like these(I made an error deliberately)

```
<pre><code>
<hr/>

Code A : 

string[] arguments = 
{
    @"Sample Data\EEEEEEE.tif",
    @"Sample Data\marbles.tif",
    "MergeTiffImages.tif"
};
TiffCP.Program.Main(arguments);

===> nothing return

<hr/>

Code B :

System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"TiffCP.exe";
string path1 = @"Sample Data\EEEEEEE.tif";
string path2 = @"Sample Data\marbles.tif";
string path3 = "MergeTiffImages.tif";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + path1 + "\"" + ", \"" + path2 + "\"" + ", \"" + path3 + "\"";
p.Start();
string t = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

===> string t => ""

<hr/>

Code C :

Process myProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"TiffCP.exe");
string path1 = @"Sample Data\EEEEEEE.tif";
string path2 = @"Sample Data\marbles.tif";
string path3 = "MergeTiffImages.tif";
myProcessStartInfo.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + path1 + "\"" + ", \"" + path2 + "\"" + ", \"" + path3 + "\"";
myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
myProcess.Start();
StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardError;
string t = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
myProcess.Close();
===> string t => Open: Failed to open "Sample Data\EEEEEEE.tif" 

</code></pre>
```

but it does not pass catch block

Is it possible to get Errors from TIFFCP.exe? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these "*first chance exceptions*" by any chance

Comment: It won't trigger an exception because your process is working correctly, without error. Faulting applications should return a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch exceptions from processes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320767/how-to-catch-exceptions-from-processes-in-c-sharp)

Comment: [Secondary duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279181/catch-another-process-unhandled-exception) which looks at launching external .NET executables within the same process, and catching their exceptions that way.

Comment: Thanks provide me a lot of information.
I will take "copy original code".
I think it's easy for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you tried two different methods. As others said, *Code B* won't give you any exception as you can't catch those of a different process.

*Code A* if you look at the [source](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/blob/master/TiffCP/Program.cs) returns nothing. So it is normal. From there you have two choices: either you copy the code from the **main** method of this source and manage yourself exceptions OR you get the output and manage errors from there.

Comment: Thanks Master. 
I understand that it can't catch error from different process. 
I search and found source of TIFFCP.exe  as you mentioned.
Then I including two files to my Project and run this Project.
But still can't catch error because On the Code like this 

    using (Tiff inImage = Tiff.Open(fileAndPageNums[0], "r"))
    {
        if (inImage == null)
            return;

if it could not find files return null....
I think I have to little more fix these files but I can see the light at the end.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: You are welcome. If and only if this answer fits your need, you shall accept it.